# have the pointer select beginning of text in a html input?

Tags: jquery, input

I am trying to mimic the search bar at http://grooveshark.com. I having almost everything down except I don't know how to place the pointer at the beginning of the text instead of at the end.

How can I have it so when a user clicks in the field, it goes to the front of the "Search" text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a watermark, take a look at this `jQuery` watermark plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jq-watermark

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a placeholder - which is a standard attribute for text fields in html5, but can also be achieved with javascript. if you are familiar with jQuery check out: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder